# Passing a text input between screens in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am having trouble taking a text input value from one screen and passing it as the text in a label in another screen.  I want to take the text input from a *TeamNameSelect* screen and have those be the text values in the labels of a *GameWindow* screen.  I've tried going through similar questions and answers on here but have been unable to get this to work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**.py file**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class NewGame(Screen):
    pass

class GameWindow(Screen):
    def teamNames(self, *args):
        self.teamOne_input.text = self.manager.ids.TeamNameSelect.ids.teamOne.text
        self.teamTwo_input.text = self.manager.ids.TeamNameSelect.ids.teamTwo.text
    pass

class TeamNameSelect(Screen):
    pass


class WinMan(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")
sm = WinMan()

screens = [NewGame(name='goBack'), TeamNameSelect(name='teamSelect'), GameWindow(name='startGame')]

for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)

sm.current = 'goBack'

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**.kv file**

```
<TeamNameSelect>:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: 10
            Label:
                text: 'Team 1 Name: '
            TextInput:
                id: teamOne
                text: ''
                multiline: False
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: 10
            Label:
                text: 'Team 2 Name: '
            TextInput:
                id: teamTwo
                text: ''
                multiline: False

        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'Go  Back'
                on_release: root.manager.current = 'goBack'
            Button:
                text: 'Game On!'
                on_release:
                    root.manager.current = 'gameWindow'
                    root.teamNames()

<GameWindow>:
    teamOne_input: teamOne_input
    teamTwo_input: teamTwo_input

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: (1, 0.1)
            Button:
                text: '. . .'
                on_release: root.manager.current = 'goBack'
            Label:
                font_size: 33
                text: 'Team'

            Label:
                font_size: 33
                id: teamOne_input
                text: ''
            Label:
                font_size: 33
                text: 'Team'
            Label:
                font_size: 33
                id: teamTwo_input
                text: ''

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: (0.75,1)
            Label:
                font_size: 33
                text: '' # Instructions on how to play game
            Label:
                font_size: 39
                text: '' # Future playing area to develop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 preliminary errors:

- There is no Screen with name "gameWindow" so I suppose the OP wanted to write "startGame".
- The root in on_release is the "TeamNameSelect" that clearly has nothing that does not have the `teamNames()` method.

On the other hand the "manager" is not implemented in the .kv so it cannot have any "id", the solution is to access the screen with name "teamSelect" using the `get_screen()` method.

Considering the above, the solution is:

```
class GameWindow(Screen):
    def teamNames(self):
        select_screen = self.manager.get_screen("teamSelect")
        self.teamOne_input.text = select_screen.ids.teamOne.text
        self.teamTwo_input.text = select_screen.ids.teamTwo.text
```

```
Button:
    text: 'Game On!'
    on_release:
        root.manager.current = 'startGame'
        root.manager.current_screen.teamNames()
```